# Converting CR to LF using sed

Tags: windows, sed

I had a file containing CR and CRLF on Windows.

I ran this command on it:

```
$ sed -i 's \x0d \x0a ' foo
```

What I got back was that:

1. All CR that were not followed by LF were converted to LF

But

2. Those CR that were part of CRLF were left unchanged.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of this behavior is that lines ending with `\r` in unix appear as ONE line with the next line that has a `\n`:

```
$ echo -e "line1\rline2\r\nline3" |cat -A
line1^Mline2^M$
line3$
```

As a result your sed, without g option, will replace the first \r in this "concatenated" line :

```
$ echo -e "line1\rline2\r\nline3" |sed 's \x0d \x0a ' |cat -A
line1$
line2^M$ #this is same input line as line1 and thus \r is not replaced the second time in the same line without g
line3$
```

You need to include g for global replacements of `\r` when found more than once in the same whatever considered to be input line:

```
$ echo -e "line1\rline2\r\nline3\rline4\r\nline5\r\nline6" |cat -A
line1^Mline2^M$   #line2 \r will not be replaced without g
line3^Mline4^M$   #line4 \r will not be replaced without g
line5^M$          # This \r will be replaced since it is unique on input line 
line6$

$ echo -e "line1\rline2\r\nline3\rline4\r\nline5\r\nline6" |sed 's \r \n ' |cat -A
line1$
line2^M$
line3$
line4^M$
line5$  #the \r is removed from here even without g , since input line5 was alone
$
line6$

$ echo -e "line1\rline2\r\nline3\rline4\r\nline5\r\nline6" |sed 's \r \n g' |cat -A
line1$
line2$
$
line3$
line4$
$
line5$
$
line6$
```

Attention:
As it is obvious from above tests , replacing `\r` with `\n` will make `CRLF` to be `LFLF` = `\n\n` and this will generate an extra blank line. This may or may not be desirable. This extra line can be removed as advised i.e by answer of mklement0

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you're running this on a *Unix* platform, using *GNU* `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/\r/\n/g; s/\n$//' foo
```

This replaces all isolated CR (`\r`, `\x0d`) instances as well as CRLF (`\r\n`, `\x0d\x0a`) sequences with *one* LF (`\n`, `\x0a`) each - see bottom for an explanation.

---

As for **what you tried** (again, assuming that you're running this on a *Unix* platform, using *GNU* `sed`):

- `sed` reads everything up to, but not including, a LF (`\n`) as a single line, and, on *output*, terminates that line with LF.
- In your case that means that a single line read would *end* in CR (`\r`) (due to `sed` reading up to CRLF, stripping the LF), possibly containing *isolated* CR instances in that line.
- `'s \x0d \x0a '`, due to not using option `g`, replaces *at most 1* CR character with LF.

What that *should* have resulted in:

- The *first* CR (`\r`, `\x0d`) instance on each line should have been replaced with LF (`\n`, `\x0a`)
- Any additional CR instances on the current line - including one that is part of the line-ending CRLF sequence - would have been left alone.

---

#### Why does a correct solution need *two* `s` calls?

- `'s/\r/\n/g'` *globally* (`g`) replaces *all* CR (`\r`) instances in the current line with LF `\n`.
- Since the CR that was part of the line-ending CRLF was therefore also replaced with `\n`, the in-memory line (the *pattern space*, in `sed` speak) now *ends in `\n`*.
- Because `sed` invariably *appends* an LF (`\n`) on output, the extra trailing `\n` must be removed, which is what `s/\n$//'` does.

Comment: Very useful for renormalising in git if there are CRs as well as CRLFs in old text files that need bringing up to date